# How to encode the following URL using Javascript or jQuery properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I want to do is encode the following link properly, but for some reason "#" is giving me a problem:

```
var text = "hello, how are you? &am fine"
var link = "http://example.com/test#zzzzzzzzz"


url = "http://twitter.com/share?url=" + link + "&text" + text;
$("#twitter a").attr("href", url)
```

I tried `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent`, but still have issue with "#". If I manually replace "#" with "%23", then for some reason the code is encoded again. Does the jQuery `attr()` preform any encoding at all?

EDIT
Trying escape produces

```
http://twitter.com/share?url=http%253A//example.com/test%2523zzzzzzzz
```

Not sure where the "%25" is coming from rather than just %23

Using `encodeURIComponent` generates the following after doing `$("#twitter a").attr("href", url)`. Where is the %25 is coming from?

```
http://twitter.com/share?url=http%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Ftest%2523zzzzzzzz
```

Comment: %25 is the percent symbol from the first round of encoding

Answer (score 21):

[`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) **should work for you**:

```
var text = "hello, how are you? & fine";
var link = "http://example.com/test#zzzzzzzzz";

var url = "http://twitter.com/share?url=" + encodeURIComponent(link) + "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(text);

$('#twitter a').attr('href', url);
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/MUZDL/1/)

Comment: this is what is generated using $.attr() http://twitter.com/share?url=http%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Ftest%2523zzzzzzzz

Comment: @Mark K, Try my new answer. I'm trying this in Chrome and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

encodeURIComponent is not "complete", you can use a custom function like this (taken from http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode/ ) :

```
function encode(toEncode) {
    return encodeURIComponent(toEncode)
        .replace(/!/g, '%21')
        .replace(/'/g, '%27')
        .replace(/\(/g, '%28')
        .replace(/\)/g, '%29')
        .replace(/\*/g, '%2A');
}
```

Example : 
    var url = encode(url_plain_text);

Answer (score 0):

According to Firebug:

```
>>> encodeURIComponent("http://example.com/test#zzzzzzzzz")
"http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftest%23zzzzzzzzz"
```

What issues are you having with the '#'?

Comment: Yes, that is what Firebug is generating which is correct, but somehow the result of $.attr() is not the same as what you mentioned.

Comment: I think something else is going wrong. If you do on this very page in Firebug `$("a[href=/users/3191/domenic]").attr("href", "http://twitter.com/share?url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://example.com/test#zzzzzzzzz"))` you find that the links for my username end up being properly encoded to what you want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

**encodeURIComponent** works fine for me. we can give the url like this in ajax call.The code shown below :

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://atandra.mivamerchantdev.com//mm5/json.mvc?Store_Code=ATA&Function=Module&Module_Code=thub_connector&Module_Function=THUB_Request",
            data: "strChannelName=" + $('#txtupdstorename').val() + "&ServiceUrl=" + encodeURIComponent($('#txtupdserviceurl').val()),
            dataType: "HTML",
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            }
        });
```